# Axlsx Gem:Ruby - Creating A dropdown

Tags: ruby, excel, dropdown, axlsx

```
wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Report') do |sheet|
  sheet.add_data_validation("D25", {
    :type => :list,
    :formula1 => 'list!D11:D17',
    :showDropDown => false,
    :showInputMessage => true,
    :promptTitle => 'blah blah',
    :prompt => 'Please select a valid blah'
    })
end
```

I have no idea how to populate the dropdown. The template shows a caret which tells me that it knows I want this to be a dropdown.

Comment: To enter a code example you can use 4 spaces. I added a `end` to your code, but it would be fine if you provide a complete minimal workig example.

Answer (score 6):

With your `formula1 => 'list!D11:D17'` you reference on another Worksheet named `list`.

If you reference only `D11:D17` you get the values from the selected area:

```
require 'axlsx'

Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  wb = p.workbook
    wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Report') do |sheet|
      sheet.add_data_validation("A10", {
        :type => :list,
        :formula1 => 'A1:A9',
        :showDropDown => false,
        :showInputMessage => true,
        :promptTitle => 'blah blah',
        :prompt => 'Please select a valid blah'
        })
    end
      p.serialize('simple.xlsx')
      puts "Wrote simple.xlsx"
end
```

You can use your `list!`-reference, but then you must name your sheet `list`.

Example:

```
require 'axlsx'

Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  wb = p.workbook
    wb.add_worksheet(name: 'list') do |sheet|
      1.upto(10){|i| sheet.add_row([i])}
    end

    wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Report') do |sheet|
      sheet.add_data_validation("A1", {
        :type => :list,
        :formula1 => 'list!A1:A9',
        :showDropDown => false,
        :showInputMessage => true,
        :promptTitle => 'blah blah',
        :prompt => 'Please select a valid blah'
        })
    end
      p.serialize('simple.xlsx')
      puts "Wrote simple.xlsx"
end
```

Comment: Thanks @knut. What if I need a list of custom text strings in the dropdown? Text strings which are not stored in any of the worksheets.

Comment: @SagarA Actually I have no idea. But you could make a new question for this problem.